# remote access to VM with independent network

Tags: vmware-esxi, rdp, anyconnect, vmware-horizon-view

We have several windows 10 VMs on an ESXi which we use RDP to connect to those VMs. On those VMs we have Cisco Anyconnect. The problem is Anyconnect will drop all other connections, as a result,  RDP will be disconnected and somebody has to go through vCenter or ESXi console and disconnect the VPN. I can give every user a VMRC access but I don't like to go through that route. I thought VMware Horizon is the solution and installed it as a test, the same result as RDP.
I know there is split tunneling option for AnyConnect but it is customer site and I do not have control on that part. I would appreciate if somebody point me to the right product and solution  for this scenario?

Comment: It sounds like the default gateway is being redirected down the VPN tunnel. Short of giving staff VRMC access, you will need to liaise with your customer to enable split tunnelling.

Comment: As I mentioned split tunneling is not an option and and no, it is not changing the gateway.

Comment: Ok, well based on what you wrote word-for-word, it said you don't have control over that part, didn't say it wasn't an option. Also, if a user RDPs into a server, connects to a VPN and then loses RDP, it 99% looks like the RDP traffic is being routed over the VPN, hence the drop in connectivity. Most of the time, this indicates the VPN is redirecting all non-local traffic over the VPN.

Comment: AnyConnect adds a virtual lan card and routes all traffic to that virtual lan card. If by changing gateway you mean that. you are correct.